# Delete Private Key from Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

For the past few days, I have been working on trying to delete a generated private key from the keychain. I have been doing my best to follow the documentation Apple provides to delete keys, which you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/updating_and_deleting_keychain_items), but I haven't been able to figure out where I am going wrong. Below is my current code for it:

```
func deleteKey() {
    var secret: AnyObject?
    // Retrieve Private Key
    let tag = "tag".data(using: .utf8)!
    print(secret)

    let getQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey, // This is a query we make to find the Private key in the key chain based of the input we put inside of it
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag, // We use the tag to search for our saved Private key in the KeyChain as it is unique
        kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, // This says the keychain will be of type RSA
        kSecReturnRef as String: kCFBooleanTrue,// This says to return a reference to the key, and not the key data itself
    ]

    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(getQuery as CFDictionary, &secret)
    print(secret!)

    let delQuery: [String: Any] = [
        kSecMatchItemList as String: secret,// Key to delete
    ]

    let delStatus = SecItemDelete(delQuery as CFDictionary)

    guard delStatus == errSecSuccess || delStatus == errSecItemNotFound else {
        print(delStatus)
        print("Error")
        return
    }

    print ("success")
```

My delStatus variable keeps on returning "-50", which I know means there is something wrong with my search parameters in the query, but I honestly can not figure it out. While I wait for an answer, I will keep trying to figure it out, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gable: check this library https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift

Comment: Definitely able to use the above link to get what I need. Thank you @Levin